# SikuliX で xlsx ファイルを読み込もうとするとエラーが出てしまう

Tags: python, sikulix

sikuliで`.xlsx`ファイルを読み込もうと思い、以下のコードを書きました。

```py
import xlrd
filename = "C:\RPA\WordPress SikuliyouSite.xlsx"
openfile = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
```

これを実行したところ以下のようなメッセージが出てきました。

```
[error] script [ WordPress2 ] stopped with error in line 7
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException ( org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser )
[error] --- Traceback --- error source first
line: module ( function ) statement 
91: expat (  __init__ )     self._reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(_xerces_parser_name)
59: expat (  ParserCreate )     return XMLParser(encoding, namespace_separator)
1480: ElementTree (  __init__ )     parser = expat.ParserCreate(encoding, "}")
651: ElementTree (  parse )     parser = XMLParser(target=TreeBuilder())
1184: ElementTree (  parse )     tree.parse(source, parser)
333: xlsx (  process_rels )     tree = ET.parse(stream)
809: xlsx (  open_workbook_2007_xml )     x12book.process_rels(zflo)
130: __init__ (  open_workbook )     bk = xlsx.open_workbook_2007_xml(
7: main (  <module> )     openfile = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
[error] --- Traceback --- end --------------
```

このメッセージの意味が分からず困っています。
どうすればファイルが読み込めるようになるでしょうか？

現在やったこととしては、pythonのインストールを行いコマンドプロンプトで
`py -m pip install xlrd` と打ち込み実行したところまでです。

具体的な解決方法があれば教えていただけたら幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 利用されているSikuliXやJythonのバージョンを記載すると回答が得やすくなるかもしれません。というのも、記載されているsikuliとSikuliXは別物のようで、また、SikuliXの方では [類似するエラーを作者が認識](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX1/issues/426) されているようなのでJythonのバージョンに起因している可能性があるように思います。

Comment: SikulixIDE-1.1.4で実行したところエラーが出ずに正常終了しました。そして同一の環境に2.0.5をダウンロードして実行したところエラーが再現しました。公式からたどれる[Download project files](https://launchpad.net/sikuli/+download)から1.1.3をダウンロードしてエクセル関連はこちらのjarファイルを使えば対策できるかもしれませんが、残念なダウングレードなので解決になっていない感があります。

Comment: payanecoさんありがとうございます。
紹介してもらったバージョンを使えば、起動することができました。

しかし、その後2.0.5を起動し別のプログラムを起動したら以下のようなコードが出ました。

Exception in thread "Thread-35" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\Lib\sikuli\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Sikuli import *
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\Lib\sikuli\Sikuli.py", line 23, in <module>
    import org.sikuli.script.Do as Do
ImportError: No module named Do

どうしたらまた使えるようになるのでしょうか？